# Hosting proccess that listens to custom port Google Compute Engine

Tags: tcp, google-compute-engine, flume-ng

This question could apply to any Java process that listens on a port on a VM instance on Google Compute Engine.

I'm trying to establish a TCP connection on port 9090, where an Apache Flume-ng process is running on the VM. I've added a firewall rule for 0.0.0.0/0 TCP:9090 on the default network, and I can see the process is listening on that port.

I have tried both the ephemeral host IP, and static host IP when trying to connect. I'm trying to connect via a Flume-ng client on a local Web app, which when configured for local routing works. It is configured like such

```
<appender name="FlumeAppender" type="DotNetFlumeNG.Client.log4net.FlumeAppender, DotNetFlumeNG.Client.log4net">
  <client>Thrift</client>
  <host>IP Address</host>
  <!--<host>127.0.0.1</host>-->
  <port>9090</port>
</appender>
```

I'm seeing TCP SocketExceptions from the flume client, does the application that is attempting to make the connection to port 9090 on GCE need to establish its own OAuth credentials? Or is there something else that I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I never used Apache Fume-ng, but wherever you've configured port to 9090 change binding/listening IP from localhost to 0.0.0.0 and it should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately my Flume config file binds to 0.0.0.0 already :/

`# For each one of the sources, the type is defined
bourne.sources.r1.type = thrift
bourne.sources.r1.bind = 0.0.0.0
bourne.sources.r1.port = 9090`

Comment: I am worried/wondering that/if Google requires OAuth when trying to establish a TCP connection to a VM instance? The library I'm using doesn't allow for that, so I'd have to make some changes

Comment: No, OAth or other authentication methods are not required to connect to TCP port of services running on GCE VM. Use a telnet client from different computer to connect to your IP/port to see if you can get in or get refused: **telnet** **<IP Address>** **9090**

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm thinking that my office might be blocking certain outgoing ports... I haven't tried this from home yet, I will tonight and mark as answered if that is the problem.